# What is a Dirac distribution on a hyperplane?

Tags: probability, distributions, sparse, approximate-inference

I'm trying to understand message passing for compressed sensing. I came acrross this distribution:
[image]

As the title suggests, how does this distribution look like? I know the first products term in the right hand side is student distribution. But what happen when it's multiplied by the second term? Also, what is the "ds" in the left hand side of (2)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Comment: @kevin012 what is "ds" in the left side of (s)?

Comment: It's a mathematical notation from measure theory when the random variable is continuous. The left side is the same meaning as the probability density for a random variable $s$.

Comment: @kevin012 still not clear. What is Dirac distribution on a hyperplane?

Comment: I'm not sure what the formula means because I don't know the context. The literal meaning is that the hyperplane is defined in the random vector space. And the Dirac delta function is defined on the subspace. If you want me to explain the concept, you need to give me more context on how the formula started.

Comment: @kevin012 I came across this in this reference: "Message Passing Algorithms for Compressed Sensing: I. Motivation and Construction" by Donoho, Maleki, and Montanari. Also, I've asked a new question related to all of this here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474137/how-to-do-sparse-signal-recovery-using-approximate-message-passing

Comment: It means that they give the constraint as a hyperplane. And the Dirac delta has non-zero value only when it is on the hyperplane. The Dirac delta is defined properly only in terms of integral. So if you take integral of distribution by the variable s, you will pick the distribution of the product of exponentials only if the values are in the hyperplane. It's one way of writing down the constraint which has to be satisfied.

Comment: So let's break it down. If N=2 and n=1 how (2) would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the example when $N = 3$ and $n = 2$.

In the case, we are in the 3-dimensional space and we are handling of constraint which is in a plane.

As the plane is two dimensional, Dirac delta has two components which is represented by product:

$$\delta_{\{y_1 = (As)_1\}} \cdot \delta_{\{y_2 = (As)_2\}}$$

where
$(As)_1$ is the first component of multiplication of $As$.

If you calculate a probability for the whole space, you need to calculate multiple integrals.

For example,

\begin{aligned}
\int_{s_1= -\infty}^{s_1 = \infty} & \int_{s_2 = -\infty}^{s_2 = \infty} \int_{s_3 = -\infty}^{s_3 =\infty}\mu(\mathrm{d}s) \\
& =  \int_{s_1= -\infty}^{s_1 = \infty} \int_{s_2 = -\infty}^{s_2 = \infty} \int_{s_3 = -\infty}^{s_3 =\infty} P(s) \cdot \delta_{\{y_1 = (As)_1\}} \cdot\delta_{\{y_2 = (As)_2\}} \mathrm{d} s_1 \mathrm{d} s_2 \mathrm{d} s_3 \\
& = \int_{a= -\infty}^{a = \infty} \int_{b = -\infty}^{b = \infty} P(a, b) \mathrm{d} a \mathrm{d} b 
\end{aligned}

where

$$P(s) = \dfrac{1}{Z}\prod\limits_{i=1}^{N}\exp(-\beta|s_i|)$$

and $\mathrm{d}a$ and $\mathrm{d}b$ are differentials on the hyperplane defined by the Dirac delta.

The Dirac delta function is to take the value which is satisfied by the hyperplane constraint. The integral in the 3D space is converted into the integral on the 2D hyperplane.

Comment: Why do you need the integration? I mean why do you need to find a probability for the whole space? Why do we need to integrate a PDF? Is the integration of $\mu (ds)$ over the whole space equals to one?

Comment: @AymenKareem Dirac delta is not the function in the ordinary sense. It gives sensible value only with the integral.